# maven mojo for reading app classes and generating java

Tags: maven, code-generation, maven-mojo

I want to write a maven plugin which will explore the classpath of my application at build time, search for classes with a certain annotation, and generate some java code adding utilities for these classes, which should get compiled in the JAR of the application.

So I wrote a mojo, inheriting from `AbstractMojo`, and getting the project through:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

I have most of the code, and my mojo does get execute, but I'm having trouble inserting my mojo at right build phase.

If I plug it like that:

```
@Mojo(name = "generate", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES,
      requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE)
```

then the java code which I generate is compiled in the JAR file.

Note that I use `project.addCompileSourceRoot` to register the output folder.

But that isn't enough for me because it's too early in the build: I cannot read the classpath and find the classes from my project. I think they're not compiled yet.

I search for classes like so:

```
        final List<URL> urls = List.ofAll(project.getCompileClasspathElements())
                .map(element -> Try.of(() -> new File(element).toURI().toURL()).get());
        final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toJavaList().toArray(new URL[0]), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        final Set<Class<?>> entities = HashSet.ofAll(new Reflections(classLoader).getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class));
```

(I'm using [vavr](http://vavr.io) but you get the gist in any case)

So, by plugging my code at the `GENERATE_SOURCES` phase, this code doesn't work and I don't find any classes.

However, if I plug my mojo at the `PROCESS_CLASSES` phase:

```
@Mojo(name = "generate", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_CLASSES,
    requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE)
```

Then my classes are found, I can access the rest of the code from the application, but the code that I generate is not taken into account in the build, despite using `addCompileSourceRoot`.

How do I get both features working at the same time: ability to explore code from the rest of the application *and* ability to generate code which will be compiled with the rest of the JAR?

I guess a possible answer would be "you can't", but as far as I can tell, [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com) and [immmutables](http://immutables.github.io/) are doing it (I tried reading their source but couldn't find the relevant code).

Comment: Such things should be solved by an annotation processor which can be bound to maven-compiler-plugin as far as i know...

Comment: Aha i understand.. That could explain why I had trouble tracking the code in immutables or querydsl. Maybe you could write an answer with a link to documentation or to an example?

Comment: PROCESS_CLASSES comes after COMPILE; you probably need to run before.  You've checked the reference?  http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html  What about PROCESS_SOURCES?  What about using the POM to configure (and change) the phase to see which works.  Finally, maybe check the Maven source.

Comment: so i need after compile because i read the existing code. @khmarbaise if you create an answer mentioning the annotation processor i'll give the answer to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @khmarbaise was right, what I wanted was not a maven mojo, but rather a maven annotation processor.

I found that [this walkthrough](http://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder) was very helpful in creating one, and also [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660469/get-field-class-in-annotations-processor/17660882#17660882) came in handy.